# aws lambda cannot start step functions in eu-west-1

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have lambda function that starts AWS Step Functions. Step Function is defined in eu-west-1. My lambda function is in eu-central-1 and I am able to launch step functions from lambda.
I copy/paste lambda function to eu-west-1, assign same role but step function is not started. When I hit test, I get wait cursor and after specified timeout, execution of lambda is stopped. Code blocks at `startExecution`

```
var stepfunctions = new aws.StepFunctions();
console.log("params: " + JSON.stringify(params)); // This is printed
let result = await stepfunctions.startExecution(params, function(err, data) {
```

To emphasize once more. Same code, same role works in eu-central-1 but not in eu-west-1. In both case runtime is Node.js 12.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem was in VPC configuration. VPC was asigned to lambda. It disables access to AWS services. Endpoint to com.amazonaws.eu-west-1.states should be added to VPC.